# Powerpoint - revealing bullets in order of audience participation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Is it possible to easily reveal bullet points in an order given by audience participation, where the answer may differ each time?  eg  What are the colours of the rainbow?

Answer (score 1):

I would try doing this with a shape to click on that would reveal the text. As the presenter, you'd have to remember where they were in the list, but then your speaker notes could show that I suppose.